# vscode python plugin: autocomplete is not working sometimes

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code + Python plugin. It's auto-complete usually works well. However, it doesn't work for libsecret.

Working:

[image: Working screenshot]

Not working:

[image]

But python from terminal always has auto-complete working. (PYTHONPATH is empty)

[image]

I searched the Internet and somebody mentioned `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`. But I think it should work out-of-box. Because `/usr/bin/python` can find the module without any other configuration, `vscode` should also find it.